# Symfony WHERE-SQL - “SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error"

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I am a newbie in symfony.  Whenever I type php symfony select-sql, I get the following error:

```
public function test(Connection $connection, request $request){
      $id = $request -> query->get('id');
      $rows = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM question WHERE qcm_fk_id=$id');
```

The sql syntax is wrong , 
[$id is an integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwjHL.jpg)

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM question WHERE
>   qcm_fk_id=$id'
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found (qcm_fk_id=$id)

OR

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation (qcm_fk_id={$id})

Comment: Variables are not expanded when using single quotes, use double quotes `"SELECT * FROM question WHERE qcm_fk_id=$id"` or better yet, prepared statements. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, it worsk now with double quotes!